# Balanced forces in scales

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, equilibrium, statics, scales

We have scales-like mechanism with a spring. Rigidity of the spring $C=10\ \mathrm{kg/cm}$, initial length $L_0=60\ \mathrm{mm}$ and diameter $d=\ \mathrm{10mm}$.

Without any weight the scales are in the "upper" position, length of the spring is $L_1=105\ \mathrm{mm}$.

The weight $P$ is put on top, scales move to the lower position, length of the spring in this position $L_2=140\ \mathrm{mm}$. More dimensions are given on the sketch.

[image: diagram of scale with measurements]

[image: simplified force diagram]

The force $P$ must be equalized by two forces $F_{O1}$ and $F_{O2}$ (which are equal, so I'll take $F_O$):

$$P=2F_{O}\cos \alpha \tag{1}$$

The force $F_S$ applied by the spring and the reaction force $F_R$ are equalized on the level around $O$:

$$L_{OB_2} F_S \cos \alpha = L_{OA_2} F_R \sin \beta\tag{2}$$

Forces along $OA_2$ must be equalized as well:

$$F_O =  F_S \sin \alpha - F_R \cos \beta \tag{3}$$

The force of the spring $F_S$ should be somehow derivable from rigidity, diameter and difference in length, so I assume this can be calculated. Dimensions are given, angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$ can be derived from dimensions.

So from (2) we could find $F_R=\frac{L_{OB_2} F_S \cos \alpha}{L_{OA_2} \sin \beta}$

From (3) we then find $F_O$ and then from (1) we find $P$.

Actually, we will need to find $P_1$ and $P_2$ for higher and lower positions. The resulting $P_2-P_1$ gives $P$.

My main difficulty is understanding the balance of forces on $OA_2$, in particular which forces are applied and how they are balanced. Can $OA_2$/$OB_2$ be seen as a lever as I did in (2)?

Comment: @DavidZ Not quite sure what I did wrong. Isn't the question about a specific physics concept? Didn't I show effort? I'd love to improve the question but I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: The only thing I can find that you actually asked is "Am I on the right track?" and that is not about a specific physics concept. To be honest, if you really don't have a reason to think you're doing something wrong and you just want confirmation of your work, this isn't the site for that. (we do have [a list of alternatives](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/391)) But if there's something specific that you don't understand, that came up in the process of doing the problem, that might make a good question for this site.

Comment: @DavidZ I've tried to clarifed my central difficulty - would you please take a look? If not, so be it. I don't really see how to improve.

Comment: OK, that works. But when editing, you should strip out everything that isn't necessary for the question you're asking. I did a little bit of that for you in my edit, but I think there's quite a bit more you could remove from the question (e.g. after equation (2)). I'll leave that to you though.